# MakeFile: error: <jni.h>: No such file or directory

Tags: c, makefile, java-native-interface

I am trying to call java from c, and I have made the following MakeFile:

```
include ../../Makefile.defs

auto_gen=
NAME=libproto.so
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -g -Wall -fPIC
LIBS= -L'$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)' -ljvm -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/include/" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/include/linux" -I"/usr/local/lib64/kamailio/"
include ../../Makefile.modules


SOURCE=jni_wrapper.c ProtoType.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCE:.c=.o)

all: $(SOURCE) $(NAME)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(LIBS) $<

clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC); rm -f *~; rm -f .*.swp; rm -f .*.swo; rm -f *.o

java:
    javac ProtoType.java
    jar cf ProtoType.jar ProtoType.class
    javap -s -p ProtoType > sigs.txt
    cat sigs.txt
```

When I compile with make I get an error like this:

```
error: <jni.h>: No such file or directory
```

I looked through many stackoverflow pages with a similar problem but they all have same solution which I already had implemented. They said you need to link the library path to jni.h.

As you can see in my MakeFile this is being done:

```
LIBS= -L'$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)' -ljvm -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/include/" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/include/linux" -I"/usr/local/lib64/kamailio/"
```

I triple checked the directories and the permissions and everything is fine.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the end of your LIBS definition to the CFLAGS

```
CFLAGS= -g -Wall -fPIC -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/include/" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/include/linux" -I"/usr/local/lib64/kamailio/"
LIBS= -L'$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)' -ljvm
```

The -I include directories are used by the compiler not the linker.  It's the compiler that can't find your .h file.

You may also want to change the targets as follows

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LIBS)
```

This will build you .so file.